# How to open a file with the flatpack installled Atom editor in Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, command-line, atom-editor, flatpack

I installed the Atom Editor via flatpack/flathub.
When I go to the command line terminal, I would like to open a file with it.
This is what I see:

```
$ atom
Command 'atom' not found, did you mean:
  command 'adom' from snap adom (3.3.3)
  command 'atobm' from deb x11-apps (7.7+9)
  command 'atrm' from deb at (3.2.5-1ubuntu1)
  command 'atop' from deb atop (2.9.0-1ubuntu1)
  command 'atom4' from deb atom4 (4.1-9build2)
  command 'atoms' from deb horae (071~svn537+ds1-1)
See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

So, the atom editor cannot be used straight from the command line. How can I open a file with the command:

```
atom file.txt
```

Comment: Since Atom developments has ceased, you should check its fork: [Pulsar](https://pulsar-edit.dev/).

Answer (score 1):

I edited the `atom.desktop` file and found the solution. You can find it in the application menu and edit it. The command below is the command is the same command as in the `.desktop` file but the `%F` is replaced with `"$@"`.

If you put this in your `~/.bashrc` file, then you can use the `atom` function to open files.

```
atom() {
  /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=atom --file-forwarding io.atom.Atom @@ "$@" @@
}
```

When you open a new Terminal, you can use this to open the file:

```
atom file.txt
```